# Select grid row item from code

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is there any way to select a grid row from code so you can trigger the [selectionChange](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#selectionchange-eventemitter) event emitter? I don't know how to get hold of the grid component and execute the event manually.

Selection grid [sample plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gln9Cp0jAJs2KqioZl7s?p=preview)

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [selectable]="true"></kendo-grid>
```

--

Edit: If I access the grid manually by adding a #gridReference tag into the kendo-grid tag, I can access the component using

```
@ViewChild('activityGrid') gridReference: GridComponent;
```

But when executing

```
var selectionEvent = { index: 0, selected: false } as SelectionEvent;  
this.gridReference.selectionChange.emit(selectionEvent);
```

It still doesn't work. It migth work when I have to access the `SelectionService` using `unselect` but that's a private class.

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vn1pWvfTPrl8pF0NAwie)

Comment: I don't know if this would work for your purposes, but I give a hacky 'solution' for selecting a row **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41600611/1882961)**.

Comment: not really, just want a simple angular2  / api way to keep it clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible to select a row programmatically via the public API.

The selectionChange emitter is there to trigger the selectionChange event and I'm afraid it will not trigger the selection logic.

Comment: are you going to implement selection method in feature?

Comment: Yes, we will. The selection API will be expanded in order to support more advanced selection modes we are planning.

Comment: any update on this? I cannot pass in a selection that I wanna be highlighted?

Comment: Is there any news on these changes. I would like to see the SelectionEvent to pass along the target from the selectable.directive. I would like to be able to easily popup details over the grid based on the target location. I'm getting the target manually based on the passed in index but seems like this would be a simple change to the SelectionEvent object and directive. It's a nice library I just wish it was open source so the community could help out.

Comment: I just found this link for requested features. It says the grid select should be coming in September release. [Kendo Features](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/category/181393-grid)

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved now by utilizing the new [SelectionDirective](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/SelectionDirective/). It allows specifying the key to be stored when selecting a row and also the `selectedKeys` collection to hold reference to the selected keys. This also allows to programatically modify the selection.